# Neo4j : Filtering path with some nodes with cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want all path between A:Alpha and D:Alpha with only :Beta nodes between these two.
If path contains same type or other type of node then those path should discarded.

```
Sample data - 
A:Alpha->B:Beta->C:Beta->D:Alpha
A:Alpha->M:Beta->Z:Gama->P:Beta->D:Alpha
A:Alpha->S:Beta->F:Beta->I:Beta-->D:Alpha
A:Alpha->U:Beta->X:Alpha->T:Alpha->W:Beta->D:Alpha

Result should be - 
A:Alpha->B:Beta->C:Beta->D:Alpha
A:Alpha->S:Beta->F:Beta->I:Beta-->D:Alpha
```

Can any one help me with cypher for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need a variable-length path and a WHERE all() predicate to restrict the labels of the middle nodes of the path:

```
... // assume 'path' variable used in the match
WHERE all(node in nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE node:Beta)
...
```

Alternately, you can use [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_path_expander), as the options for the path expander should be able to deliver what you want:

```
MATCH (a:Alpha)
CALL apoc.path.expandConfig(a, {relationshipFilter: '>', labelFilter:'/Alpha|+Beta' filterStartNode:false}) YIELD path
RETURN path
```

The [label filter](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/index32.html#_label_filter_2) is the key here. `/Alpha` creates a termination node filter on :Alpha nodes, meaning that paths will be traversed only up to the first :Alpha node encountered and not beyond, and the paths returned will always end with an Alpha node. `+Beta` creates a whitelist filter on :Beta nodes for nodes in the path (which doesn't apply to the end node when we use a termination filter), and the `filterStartNode:false` means the start node isn't subject to the whitelist filter either.

This ensures that paths only go to the first :Alpha node, and all middle nodes in the path must be :Beta nodes.